# c# KeyPressed doesn't capture special chars

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, keylogger

I'm using a keylogger to capture keys as they are pressed.

It works fine but not for special chars as "@, +£%*¨¨" .. etc

```
private void Test_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        WriteToTextFile(sb.ToString());
    sb.Append(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Is it also possible to delete chars if users pressed Backspace key?

Comment: This is purely for educational purposes, correct? :)

Comment: ...and bold main point **KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try method `OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)` if you are working on a control. I also had the problem, that not everything was captured with `OnKeyPress`.